# "immediate_failed" - Could not automatially log in the user

Tags: web, google-plus

I have a problem when I developed my website with Google+ sign-in:
I did step by step that the doc told me but I always failed at step4:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/

the result was always ""immediate_failed" - Could not automatially log in the user", I just don't kown why, can anyone help me, thanks very much!  :-(

Comment: Could you please post the code you are working with?

Answer (score 22):

Note that in the sample code you pointed to, the "immediate_failed" check is commented out. This is intentional, since the first time a user encounters the Sign-in button on the page, it will fail.

The reason it fails is that when the page first loads, before the user even presses the button, a request is sent to Google to determine if the user has already logged in (via Google or another site, for example). If they are - there is no need for them to log in again, so the button never needs to be shown. But if they have **not** been logged in already, you will get the "immediate_failed" response, and will need to either show (or not clear) the button.

tl;dr - Don't worry aout getting immediate_failed when the page first loads. This is normal.

Comment: This is shown in a working example on the [Javascript quick start page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround I use [gapi.auth.authorize](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize) method in the gapi.auth.signIn callback. Here is my code:

```
gapi.auth.signIn({
    'callback': gPlusLoginCallback
});

function gPlusLoginCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        doSmth(authRes['access_token']); 
    } else if (authResult['error'] == "immediate_failed") {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            client_id: gplusClientId,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email',
            immediate: true
        }, function (authRes) {
            if (authRes['status']['signed_in']) {
                doSmth(authRes['access_token']);
            }
        });
    }
}

function doSmth(accessToken){
    //Do smth
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this setting  "immediate: true", to be false " immediate: false".
But if you like to make more complex implementation look at the first sample here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js. You have to calls to Google's "gapi.auth.authorize({...", the first one with "immediate: true", and the second one with "immediate: false".

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I faced this issue recently.

In my case, it was because I specified the [URI parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect?hl=en#prompt) `prompt` to `none`. I guess Google doesn't like that if the user has never been logged to your platform before.

Whenever I changed that to `consent` or totally removed it, it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was because of explicitly specifying the [authorization parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient) `prompt` to `'none'`,similar to a previous answer.

It worked for me by specifying `prompt=None` or as per the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient),you may skip this parameter.