# Google plus signin "immediate_failed" error

Tags: google-signin

I have implemented login with Google Plus in my website using Javascript SDK. when i click on button (Goolge Plus Signin) first time, it display Error "immediate_failed". but when i click second time on that button it works fine. "immediate:false or true" is not working? 
how can i solve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["immediate\_failed" - Could not automatially log in the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863349/immediate-failed-could-not-automatially-log-in-the-user)

Answer (score 4):

assuming you have implemented the client side flow described here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/?hl=en#using_the_client-side_flow and it sounds that you are calling the signin callback before rendering the button itself, but for further debug I'd need to see your code.